# Cucumber : can we execute BeforeAll and AfterAll annotations based on a condition

Tags: maven, cucumber, testng, cucumber-java

I have multiple runner classes and within hooks I have BeforeAll annotation which has code that should be executed based on specific runner.
I am using TestNG to invoke runners and as BeforeAll doesn't support parameterization, I am unable to use this approach.
Any suggestions are really appreciated

Comment: Please provide the code snippets for better understanding.